# IRI.getShortForm() does not work as expected with spaces and some extra symbols

Tags: owl-api

It seems that getShortForm() of the IRI class is not able to process the classnames with spaces and some other symbols.

Is there a method in the OWL-API that parses IRIs more corectly (the same way as Protege does).

For this code

```
 for (OWLClass cls : clses) {
     String s = cls.toString();
     String s1 = cls.asOWLClass().getIRI().getShortForm();
     System.out.println("SHORT: "+s1+"    LONG: "+s);
  }
```

I've got the following strange results:

```
SHORT: CAPECCWEAttackPatterns#DoS: resource consumption (memory)    LONG: <http://www.grsu.by/net/CAPECCWEAttackPatterns#DoS: resource consumption (memory)>
SHORT: restart    LONG: <http://www.grsu.by/net/CAPECCWEAttackPatterns#DoS: crash / exit / restart>
SHORT: data    LONG: <http://www.grsu.by/net/CAPECCWEAttackPatterns#Modify application data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRIs cannot contain spaces. They need to be escaped as `%20` sequences. The same is true for a number of other characters.

For spaces and other characters, the common approach is to use `rdfs:label` annotations. Protege has renderers that use these to show classes and properties on screen.

Comment: is there a function that is able to normalize given IRI, i.e escape all the unsafe symbols?

Comment: @geeknet Sure, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/4607733